# Swagger + Spring Boot, how to set the example value to be passed in the API based on Spring Boot Validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

In all of my API calls where I have used DTOs to pass the information, in Example values, I see all the fields of the DTO and I have applied Validation groups in my Spring Boot application on DTOs like,

```
    @NotNull(message = "error_card_expiry_month_required", groups = AddUpdateCard.class)
    @JsonProperty("month")
    private Integer Month;

    @NotNull(message = "error_card_expiry_year_required", groups = AddUpdateCard.class)
    @JsonProperty("year")
    private Integer Year;

    @NotBlank(message = "error_card_cvv_required",groups = AddUpdateCard.class)
    @JsonProperty("cvv")
    private String Cvv;
```

here I have used `groups = Class.class` for validation.

How can I tell swagger, If possible, to use this so that it doesn't show entire DTOs as example value and only show me the values that I have validated?

I just want the Validated `@NotNull` annotated values for that API only.

Is it possible or will I have to use any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to every field.

```
@ApiModelProperty(name = "The chosen month", position = 0, example = "6")
@NotNull(message = "error_card_expiry_month_required", groups = AddUpdateCard.class)
@JsonProperty("month")
private Integer Month;
```

@ApiModelProperty is used by swagger to create DTO (requestbody) for the given property.

- name: The name that should be shown by swagger as the information tag in the model
- position: The order in the requestbody that this property has
- example: A pre-filled example in the requestbody field in swagger

It might not be able to sort through valid examples based on bean validation, but since you know your own constraints you can pick whatever example value you want.

Comment: This did not work.

But how will I specify which exact API should this be seen in?

I mean the field is used in many different APIs.

Comment: You can't really do that, unless each endpoint has it's own DTO object, that way you can easily differentiate between multiple endpoints. Otherwise the example values and order will be shared if you make it that way.

Comment: So if I am using one DTO object for many endpoints, and managing the fields of the DTO using validation, then isn't it possible to achieve it?

Comment: Swagger DTO example models are created upon application startup and then become static. This means that you cannot dynamically create different DTO example models based on the same DTO object when the chosen endpoint is different. You could take a look at this url: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#overriding-property-datatypes